# Writing to stdout is slow, why still recommend to logging to stdout?

Tags: java, docker

I've been heard of it's recommended to logging to stdout not to files when running app in a container for a long time([this](https://12factor.net/logs), [this](https://success.docker.com/article/logging-best-practices#modernizetraditionalapplications) and [this](https://dzone.com/articles/containers-5-docker-logging-best-practices)).

But I found that writing to stdout is far way slower than writing to file(test code [here](https://gist.github.com/chanjarster/b547d443aaf8f141e2d59a4cd01eaeaf)), below is the result:

```
$ docker build -t console-print .
$ docker run -d --name console-print console-print 100000
$ docker logs --tail 5 console-print
lines: 100,000
stdout: 2,492 ms
file: 18 ms
```

So my question is why we still recommend logging to stdout?

Comment: Did you messure the time correctly? That is using "docker logs --tail 5 console-print" with you file aproach(asking as I see no code that supports "docker --logs" in the git).  See, if you dumped your logs to /dev/null it would be even faster - but not a fair comparison, would it?

Comment: The test code do 3 things: System.out.println 100,000 lines, write same amount lines to a file, output time they used, and then exits.`docker logs --tail 5 console-print` is used to print last 5 lines which contains the test output.

Comment: I thought so, so your meassuring different things. Try to meassure only the file aproach and only the System.out approach in separate runs. For both  attemps dump everything with  --docker logs to the shell(for the file approach you need additional code ). And messure the total time.

Comment: And FWIW most people don't want to have persistent data in a nonpersistent container ...

Answer (score 4):

The recommendation to write to STDOUT is not performance related. Passing the log output to a tool that deals with it is much easier if you let Docker read the log from STDOUT of the container. If the application first writes to a container local file, this is much more difficult.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have a slow terminal app. Try use another.

Comment: No, I used `-d` parameter.